# Call service after getting response - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Service written to get initial details and later based on its response get complete details.
The complete details can only be fetch once the email is retrieved from initial response.

```
(function () {
    function empService(mainSrv, empSrv) {
        var self = this;
        var initialDetail = mainSrv.getInitialDetails.get();
        self.getInitialDetails = function () {
            return initialDetail.$promise.then(function (data) {
                var user = data.result;
                self.fName = user.first_name;
                self.lName = user.last_name;
                self.email = user.email;
            });
        };
    var completeDetail = empSrv.getCompleteDetails.get({email : **self.email**});
        self.getCompleteDetails = function () {
            return completeDetail.$promise.then(function (data) {
                self.eDetails = data.details;
            });
        };
    }
    myServiceModule.service('empService', ['mainSrv’, 'empSrv' , empService]);
})();
```

Service/Code gets initialized the email gets undefined; mainSrv/mainService get mail details and empSrv/empService get complete details based on the email address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `.success` for example:

```
var empService = function () {
    mainSrv.getInitialDetails.get()
        .success(onGetInitDetailsSuccess())
        .error(onGetInitDetailsError())
}
$scope.onGetInitDetailsSuccess() = function (result) {
    empSrv.getCompleteDetails.get(result)
}
$scope.onGetInitDetailsError() = function (result) {
    //handle your exception here
}
```